# rails 4.1 add videos folder to asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Here are my paths so far:

```
assets
>fonts
>images
>stylesheets
>javascripts
>videos
```

I would like to bucket videos under the videos folder, but I can not seem to get them to be show up.  My current `assets.rb` initializer looks like:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( layout-home.css layout-error.css layout-static-page.css layout-brand.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( layout-home.js layout-static-page.js layout-brand.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos/**/") ]
```

Any ideas on how to adjust this? No matter how I adjust that last line, I can not get them to pull in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
```

Do not forget to restart the server after changing an initializer.

Comment: you should post where you put these assets, like in which file